# Finding the number of occurrences of an array inside a multidimensional-array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the number of occurrences of these ([0],[1],[2] etc) in an array  but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I'm trying at the moment to output the result:

```
$photos = (my entire array)
$p = $photos['photos']['photo'];
$max = (max($p));
echo $max;
```

And here's how my array looks under print_r:

```
Array
(
    [photos] => Array
        (
        [example1] => 1
        [example2] => 1
        [photo] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 726462325
                        [owner] => 985275329856
                )   
                [1] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 836252653
                        [owner] => 736053268937
                )        
                etc
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, you're trying to count the number of occurrences of *what* exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for the number of arrays inside the photo array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ryan mentioned, you need to use the [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function. This is how you would use it in your example:

```
$photos = (my entire array)
$p = $photos['photos']['photo'];
$count = count($p);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

Good luck!

Comment: The solution usually is! Glad to help